# Why does App Engine Flexible Enviroment not allow WebSockets and HTTP/2 traffic?

Tags: go, websocket, http2, gorilla, app-engine-flexible

I'm more interested in WebSocket, but after reading documentation  [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled),
I was surprised when I read that:

> The following features are not supported by App Engine flexible environment:
>   HTTP/2 traffic to the backend service, Websockets , HTTP requests that directly access instances

I was planning to build an app with gorilla-websocket, but now that I've read this, I don't know how I could accomplish it.
I understand WebSocket is not get supported in App Engine Standard Environment, but why not in the Flexible Environment?

Comment: Because it´s pretty easy to deploy an app in app engine, I don´t feel ready to manage a virtual machine, may be in one year, but not right now, I just wanna focus on my code and later on I can be learning how to manage a VM

Comment: Learn docker. That way you won't have to be limited by PAAS.

Comment: Have you found the answer useful?

Comment: no, I have not, I'm moving on to kubernetes engine, it does not have that limitation, it's kinda what @mpm and VictorHerasmePerez said, they were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other options:

> Like the standard environment, the flexible environment does not
>   support websockets. If you need to use websockets you can use [Compute
>   Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs) or [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs).

as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#websockets).

You can follow the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348) too.

---

Update:

Currently websocket support is available for following languages

- Python
- Java
- Node.js

But it's in **beta**

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity